# ¿Por que no accede al proyecto Laravel luego de ingresar mis credenciales en login.blade.php?; no valida usuario y password

Tags: laravel, login, autenticación, orm, artisan

¡Buenas noches!; tengo mi proyecto de Laravel que se llama "proyectolaravel"; de los cuales una vez de haber creado un sistema de seguridad de autenticación y verificación de credenciales con el comando de Laravel php artisan make:auth; de los cuales creo en la carpeta /resources/views/auth (el archivo de login.blade.php); en la carpeta de los controladores /App/Http/Controllers/Auth/ creó los siguientes controladores:

1. ForgotPasswordController.php
2. LoginController.php
3. RegisterController.php
4. ResetPasswordController.php
5. VerificationController.php

Y a nivel de la carpeta /App/Http/Controllers, esta el controlador HomeController.php

En el controlador LoginController.php; se ha definido 2 métodos showLoginForm y login (el primer método para mostrar el formulario login.blade.php para mostrar las credenciales del usuario que son el usuario y password; que hay un formulario que envia por action al archivo web.php que esta en /routes/web.php la ruta para llamar al método showLoginForm y Login del Controlador LoginController.php

A continuación se tiene el código del controlador LoginController.php:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('auth.login');

    }

    public function login(Request $request){

        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if (Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $request->usuario,'password' => $request->password,'condicion'=>1])){

            return redirect()->route('main');

        }
    
        return back()->withErrors(['usuario' => trans('auth.failed')]);

    }   
        
        protected function validateLogin(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'usuario' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string'
            ]);
        }


    
}
```

El  archivo de donde están las rutas en /routes/web.php de mi proyecto de laravel se tiene lo siguiente:

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/main', function () {
    return view('contenido/contenido');
})->name('main');

Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');

Route::get('/producto', 'ProductoController@index');
Route::post('/producto/registrar', 'ProductoController@store');
Route::put('/producto/actualizar', 'ProductoController@update');
Route::put('/producto/desactivar', 'ProductoController@desactivar');
Route::put('/producto/activar', 'ProductoController@activar');

Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');

Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');
Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');

Route::get('/rol', 'RolController@index');
Route::get('/rol/selectRol', 'RolController@selectRol');

Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
Route::post('/user/registrar', 'UserController@store');
Route::put('/user/actualizar', 'UserController@update');
Route::put('/user/desactivar', 'UserController@desactivar');
Route::put('/user/activar', 'UserController@activar');

Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

El archivo que muestra el formulario para ingreso de las credenciales del usuario que se llama login.blade.php que esta en /resources/views/auth/login.blade.php se tiene el siguiente codigo:

```html
@extends('auth.contenido')

@section('login')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="card-group mb-0">
          <div class="card p-4">
          <form class="form-horizontal was-validated" method="POST" action="{{ route('login')}}">
           {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center bg-success">Compras - Ventas</h3>
             
              <div class="form-group mb-3{{$errors->has('usuario' ? 'is-invalid' : '')}}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" value="{{old('usuario')}}" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                {!!$errors->first('usuario','<span class="invalid-feedback">:message</span>')!!}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-4{{$errors->has('password' ? 'is-invalid' : '')}}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="password" value="{{old('password')}}" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                {!!$errors->first('password','<span class="invalid-feedback">:message</span>')!!}
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success px-4"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-2x"></i> Iniciar sesión</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Como se puede observar en el archivo login.blade.php hay una extensión del archivo contenido.blade.php que es el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Sistema Ventas Laravel Vue Js- webtraining-it.com">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Sistema ventas Laravel Vue Js, Sistema compras Laravel Vue Js">
   
    
    <title>Proyecto</title>

  <!-- Icons -->
  <link href="css/plantilla.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="app flex-row align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
     @yield('login')
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap and necessary plugins -->
  <script src="js/plantilla.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

El problema que tengo es el siguiente que cuando ingreso las credenciales por medio del formulario que se presenta por medio del archivo login.blade.php no ingresa al proyecto a pesar de que se esta ingresando el login y password correcto y da un mensaje en la pantalla de que "Las credenciales no pertenecen a la base de datos", no se como podría solucionarlo, o ¿como hacer una manera de que si se ingresa las credenciales incorrectas se presente un formulario para ingresar los datos del usuario para crearlos o modificarlos?, su ayuda, adjunto pantalla que me sale, y print de pantalla de los usuarios creados en PHPMyAdmin

[image: Laravel - Autenticacion de credenciales del usuario login.blade.php]

[image: PhpMyAdmin usuarios creados]

¿Como puedo solucionar para que una vez ingresada las credenciales?; pueda ingresar a mi proyecto, o a su vez si no son correctas las credenciales presente o llame al modulo de usuarios para crear, editar o modificar usuarios que es componente usuarios.vue ¡Gracias!

Estimados comunidad de programadores no se si para solucionar esto tendré que aplicar lo que esta en la documentación del siguiente link o enlace:

[Laravel - hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing)

Estimados ¡Buenos días!; edite el controlador de mi proyecto "proyectolaravel" que se llama "LoginController.php" que esta dentro de la ruta /App/Http/Controllers/Auth lo indicado por el usuario de la comunidad de Stack Overflow azeós indicado así puso mi controlador:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('auth.login');

    }

    public function login(Request $request){

        $this->validateLogin($request);
 
        $this->updateLogin($request);
    
        if (Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $request->usuario,'password' => $request->password,'condicion'=>1])){

            return redirect()->route('main');

        }
    
        return back()->withErrors(['usuario' => trans('auth.failed')]);

    }   
        
        protected function validateLogin(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'usuario' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string'
            ]);
        }

        protected function updateLogin(Request $request){

            // Seleccionamos el usuario con el ID 1
            $usuario = User::find(1);

            // Editamos el password, esta vez guardando un hash del mismo
            $usuario->password = Hash::make('Josue2019');

            // Guardamos los cambios
            $usuario->save();
        }


    
}
```

Pero en el momento que llama al metodo updateLogin($request), pero en la linea de instrucción $Usuario = User::find(1);
da error que dice que no encuentra el metodo User, me valí también de lo que dice una página WEB:

[Uso del Método Find](https://ajgallego.gitbooks.io/laravel-5/content/base_de_datos_eloquent_orm.html)

Adjunto el mensaje de error que me sale:

[image: Mensaje de error en el método Find() de Laravel]

Comment: Veo que tenés guardado el password en texto plano (al menos el de `jfrugne1970`). Laravel genera un hash del password ingresado en el login y lo compara con el almacenado en la DB (espera encontrar otro hash). Como no encuentra otro hash igual, te dice que los datos son incorrectos. Actualizá tu password utilizando `Hash::make('elPassword')`. Evidentemente diste de alta a mano ese usuario o modificaste el password desde la DB.

Comment: Estimado @azeós lo que tú dices que tengo ingreso como jfrugone1970 es mi usuario pero en este caso el password es otro en este caso Josue2019; pero lo que tu dices que utilice Hash::make('elPassword') lo realice en el LoginController.php ya que la verdad no te entiendo de lo que dices que utilice hash::make('elPassword'), la verdad modifique el password desde la base de datos y lo puse Josue2019

Comment: Estimado @azeós una consulta de lo que indicas que se utiliza Hash::make('elPassword') a lo que te refieres a lo que esta en el siguiente link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing

Comment: No veo en tu archivo web.php el comando: Auth::routes(); el cual lo agrega al hacer la autentificacion basica de Laravel.  Tampoco veo el metodo __construct() en el controlador LoginController.php el cual tiene el codigo para llamar al middleware: $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(es) Comunidad de Programador de Stack Overflow en especialmente @azeós solucione el problema que tenía en el controlador LoginController.php lo que hacia falta de llamar al modelo User en la parte de arribo del Controlador de esta manera use App\User; e importe las siguientes linea de código:

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

lo que queda mi controlador "LoginController.php"; de la siguiente manera:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('auth.login');

    }

    public function login(Request $request){

        $this->validateLogin($request);
 
        $this->updateLogin($request);
    
        if (Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $request->usuario,'password' => $request->password,'condicion'=>1])){

            return redirect()->route('main');

        }
    
        return back()->withErrors(['usuario' => trans('auth.failed')]);

    }   
        
        protected function validateLogin(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'usuario' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string'
            ]);
        }

        protected function updateLogin(Request $request){

            // Seleccionamos el usuario con el ID 1
            $usuario = User::find(1);

            // Editamos el password, esta vez guardando un hash del mismo
            $usuario->password = Hash::make('Josue2019');

            // Guardamos los cambios
            $usuario->save();
        }


    
}
```

Entrando normal a mi proyecto, a continuación adjunto la pantalla de la pantalla principal del proyecto, que ingresa con normalidad

[image: Proyecto Laravel]

Answer (score 1):

El password que tiene que estar guardado en la base de datos es una password [*hasheado*](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/hashing), no el password en *texto plano*.

Si te fijás, el password del usuario `patricio2` es una secuencia de letras y números, y obviamente ese no *es* su password, es un hash del mismo.
En cambio, el password del usuario `jfrugne1970` está en texto plano, es decir, puedo leer cual es.

---

**¿Cuál es el problema (además del riesgo de seguridad)?**

Al loguearte, Laravel lo que hace es buscar en la DB si existe un usuario con con el nombre ingresaro y el *hash* de la contraseña ingresada, no busca la contraseña en texto plano. Como ese usuario si tiene guardada la contraseña en texto plano, y Laravel está buscando un hash, te dice que los datos ingresados no son correctos.

**¿Cómo solucionarlo?**

Desde cualquier controlador (o desde donde quieras), editá la contraseña de ese usuario y guardá un hash de la misma.
Ejemplo:

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Seleccionamos el usuario con el ID 1
        $usuario = User::find(1);

        // Editamos el password, esta vez guardando un hash del mismo
        $usuario->password = Hash::make('Josue2019');

        // Guardamos los cambios
        $usuario->save();
    }
}
```

En este caso lo hice dentro del HomeController, lo que en tus rutas corresponde a `/home`. Con lo cual, después de agregar eso al controlador, entrá una vez a `/home`, después abrí phpMyAdmin y fijate si cambió correctamente la contraseña. Si es así, borrá lo que agregaste en el controlador y probá loguearte otra vez.

**¿Cómo evitar el problema?**

Nunca cargues a mano una contraseña directamente en la DB, siempre hacelo mediante la [*facade Hash*](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/hashing) de Laravel.

Comment: Estimado @azeós ¡Buenos días!; hice lo que me dijiste hice cambios en el controlador LoginController.pgp que lo puedes ver en la parte de arriba, pero me da un error al tratar de ejecutar $Usuario = User::find(1); no se ¿cuál es el problema?; en la parte de arriba de tu contestación esta el controlador LoginController.php con el cambio que realice

Comment: @JoseFernandoFrugoneJaramill vi tu respuesta. Agregar `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` no hace falta porque no lo estás usando, si tenés que agregar `use App\User` y `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash` tal como figura en mi respuesta. Si te sirvió mi respuesta, marcala como correcta así queda como solucionada esta pregunta. Si consideras que tu respuesta es la adecuada, marcá la tuya, pero marcá alguna. Veo que tenés varias preguntas realizadas en el sitio, varias con respuesta, pero no marcaste ninguna como correcta.